# Trying to use Application Volatile to get a cell to display name of workbook each time it is changed, but not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use application.volatile to enable a cell to display the name of the workbook each time the workbook is opened.

```vb
Function getbookname() As String

    Application.Volatile
    getbookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name

End Function
```

I input =getbookname() into cell B7, but the results are mixed. If I close the workbook, change the name of the workbook and open again, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Is calculation set to automatic? If it's set to manual it won't update even with volatile.  Also which version of excel? 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: It's set to automatic, and is 32 bit. Even though calculation is set to automatic, still does not update.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many sites which explain why to avoid using `Volatile` unless really necessary.

In your code, you are using `ActiveWorkbook`, but your description of what you want implies that `ThisWorkbook` would be more appropriate.

You do not need VBA. From https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-the-current-Excel-file-name-path-or-worksheet-in-a-cell-186833c6-c899-4912-a14c-240c2eb51e0b:

- Insert the current file name, its full path, and the name of the
  active worksheet: `=CELL("filename")`
- Insert the current file name only:
  `=MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1,
  SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)`

If you really want to use VBA, then you can set a reference cell somewhere with the `Workbook_Open` event. This is even easier if you use a 'Named Range'. For argument, let us call this workbook-scoped named range "bookname". Then, in the cells where you need it, you can just type `=bookname`

```
Private Sub WorkBook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MyReferenceSheet").Range("bookname").Value = ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

For each of these options, "Volatile" and all the issues that this can cause is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Using the excel version is more stable, although I need to perform some kind of action before the file name updates after opening the workbook after a name change. I will try to find another workaround for that.

Comment: OK - sounds like a new question rather than trying to piggy back on this one (although you could link to it for more context). Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.